# SharePoint search only works for domain admins

Tags: search, document, library

I've been running into a problem where most accounts can't search my SharePoint main site through the search bar at the top-right of my page.  I have a document library that they need to be able to search in, and it never returns any results regardless regardless of what is searched.

[image: This is a picture of the search bar I'm referring to.]

After further testing, domain admins are able to search fine but the rest of the accounts in the domain are not.  I assume this is a simple fix, but I have been searching everywhere and have not found a solution.  Has anyone run into this?

Thank you!

EDIT:  I just tested this on the SharePoint server's admin account, and that worked too.

Comment: Is the crawl account a local account or domain account?

Comment: It says that the crawl account is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

Comment: Do you have some kind of special permissions on your site?

Comment: No, I don't.  I just changed the crawl account to a normal domain account that has local admin rights on the server, and it's crawling properly but still only displaying search results to those few select users.  Most of the permissions are pretty OOTB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added Search service account to the "Windows Authorazation Access Group?" You may follow this link to do that 
http://troygerber.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/only-get-search-results-when-logged-into-sharepoint-as-sharepoint-farm-account/

Comment: Yep, I just set my crawl account to a domain administrator, added it to the WAAG, and it still does not work.  Crawls and everything properly, but results can't be displayed to the regular users.

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1**
This may be a permissions issue. I would carefully review the permissions on that library as well as the permissions on your results.aspx page.

**Option #2**
It sounds like you may have an issue with your search results (*results.aspx*) page. More specifically, the web part where the search core results are displayed. To edit this page you can go to:

*{{yoursearchcenterpath}}/Pages/results.aspx?DisplayMode=Design&ControlMode=Edit*

I would open that web part and check your settings. Specifically ensure that your "Results Query Options" are along the lines of:

- Query Language => Browser Locale
- Cross-Web part query ID => User query
- Remove Duplicate Results => Checked
- Enable Search Term Stemming => Unchecked
- Ignore Noise Words => Checked
- Fixed Keyword Query =>
- Append Text To Query =>

Those last two are left empty.

Comment: #1. The users are able to access all of those files without the search, though. The permissions are relatively wide open, and my account even has full control of the library.  Though it cannot see any results in search.

#2.  It doesn't let me get to a regular results.aspx page, but I am able to navigate to http://sharepoint/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx? .

It also isn't letting me get to http://sharepoint/_layouts/Results.aspx?DisplayMode=Design&ControlMode=Edit, it just says that an error occurred when I try to go there.

Comment: So it sounds like option 1 isn't the problem. When you do a scoped search within the library your results page (regardless if results are displaying or not) should be results.aspx. Is this not the case?

Comment: Nope, that's not the case.  I just did a search in a library called "Test" for the item "searchtest".  It brought me this for the (empty) results page:

http://sharepoint/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=searchtest&cs=This%20List&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsharepoint%2FTest

Comment: In MOSS 2007 this problem would occur when the default zone for the web application didn't match the same URL as the start address of the content source. Changing the zone via Alternate Access Mappings (_AAM in Central Admin_) by setting the start address as the default or changing the start address in the content source normally fixed the issue. What are your settings under **Site Settings | Site Collection Administration | Search Settings**? Any custom Search Scopes under **Site Collection Administration | Search Scopes**?

Comment: Please remember to vote if this was helpful to you or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario occurs if you have a one-way trust established and are performing a search with a user from the trusted domain.

One Way Trust DiagramIn order to rectify this situation, you’ll have to configure your Search Service Application to store ACLs in Claims format. To do this, you’ll have to use PowerShell (credit goes to Sladecross for this).

```
$SearchApp = Get-SPServiceApplication %searchGUID%
$SearchApp.setproperty(“ForceClaimACLs”, 1)
```

Replace `%searchGUID%` with the `GUID` of the Search Service Application.
Run this if you know the GUID:

```
Get-SPServiceApplication
```

After you perform a full crawl, you’ll see search results, regardless of which domain you’re logged in.

I’ve also witnessed situations where the search crawling account was a domain account from the trusted domain. This does allow users from the trusted domain to perform search. However, the problem with this is twofold because configuring a managed account with an account from the trusted domain causes all sorts of wacky things:

- The inability to access the Configure Managed Accounts screen from the UI.
- When logged-in from the other domain (the non-trusted one) you won’t see search results. It becomes an either/or situation.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this blog https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2344518
It will fix your issue.

Comment: try to post main answer from the blog post. instead of posting links Thanks